# When is the map location and zoom level set?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm about to craft a map in Minecraft, but want to make one of my main base, not my snow outpost where I currently am. Is the location and zoom level set when the map is crafted, or is on first view?

If it is on craft, then I'll wait till I get back home before making it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23224/how-can-i-choose-the-zoom-level-for-my-map

Comment: The other question doesn't touch on location, just zoom so not an exact duplicate IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time you look at it. To test I crafted two maps in one location. I looked at one there and another some distance away. They both centered at the place they were first looked at, not where they were crafted, and I would assume this is where the zoom level is set as well.