# How can I create a 1:1 map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I choose the zoom level for my map?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23224/how-can-i-choose-the-zoom-level-for-my-map)

While browsing the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map_%28Item%29#Gallery), I found the picture below, which appears to have a scale of 1:1. Is this possible using the base game? Is it the work of some mod?

How can I make a 1:1 map in minecraft?

[image: hacked map]